# When trying to install arviz I get the following error msg: "Error: python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1

Tags: pip, anaconda, setuptools, arviz

I have already tried using:

```
pip install --upgrade setuptools
pip install ez_setup
```

I need to install arviz to visualize the out of pystan. 
I am using python 3 on windows 10 (anaconda distribution).

Comment: I reinstalled anaconda, it fixed the problem. However, this is not a solution.

Comment: "*I reinstalled anaconda*" If you were in a Conda environment, then you probably should have been using `conda` to upgrade the `setuptools` package and not `pip`.

Comment: I was not in anaconda environment. I was trying to install from the command line. I had already tried using `conda` as you suggested while trying to install from anaconda command prompt, but it did not help, unfortunately

Comment: Have you been able to fix it already? Which python version are you on? Do you have troubles with other packages or only arviz?